# Using switch on $_GET with if

Tags: loops, get, switch-statement, case, break

So I'm trying basically to make it like: ?p=blabla&dep=blabla

```
switch($_GET['p'])
{
case 'home':
    include("template/index.html");
    break;
case null:
    include("template/index.html");
    break;
case 'roster':
    include("template/roster.html");
    break;
case 'about':
    include("template/about.html");
    break;
case 'members':
    include("members/index.php");
    break;
}

if(($_GET['p'] == 'about') && ($_GET['dep'] == 'hospital')) 
{
    include("template/hospital.html");
}
```

And it still includes both about.html and hospital.html when I do blablabla?p=about&dep=hospital

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the if statement inside the switch case.

```
case 'about':
    if ($_GET['dep'] == 'hospital')
        include("template/hospital.html");
    else
        include("template/about.html");
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you ask for.

First you have your switch statement. It sees there is 'about' in $_GET['p'] so it will include that script.

Afterwards you have your if and this also evaluates to true, thus it's included.

To change this:

add another if in your 'about' case.

```
case 'about':
    if ($_GET['dep'] == 'hospital') break;
    include("template/about.html");
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your switch is rocessed before the line that looks for dep=hospital, so it will include about.html before it even looks for the department.

If you want to display just hospital.html, but only if p=about move the test into the case.

```
switch($_GET['p'])
{
case 'home':
  include("template/index.html");
  break;
case null:
  include("template/index.html");
  break;
case 'roster':
  include("template/roster.html");
  break;
case 'about':
  if(($_GET['dep'] == 'hospital')) {
    include("template/hospital.html");
  } else {
    include("template/about.html");
  }
  break;
case 'members':
    include("members/index.php");
    break;
```

}